# cache_page in Django 1.8 causes 'str' object does not support item assignment error

Tags: python, django, caching, cookies

I've written a wrapper for Django's cache_page decorator, so that a test function can be passed on to it. By that, e.g. only non-authenticated users get to see a cached version. Here's the wrapper's code:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
def passes_test_cache(test_func, timeout=None, using=None, key_prefix=None):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request):
                return cache_page(timeout, cache=using, key_prefix=key_prefix)(view_func)(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

It's been working nicely up to Django 1.7.x. However, with the update to Django 1.8 I'm getting the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 55, in process_response
    httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 235, in set_cookie
    self.cookies[key] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

It seems something is wrong with the cookies dict, which appears to be a string here. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way cookies work has been changed in 1.8, but your cached page still returns the 1.7 format. Just clear your cache to fix it.

Comment: I love such simple solutions! Thanks :-) As a side note: it wasn't local browser cache that had to be cleared, but our memcached instance.